# Cardinality of the setof $L$-structures on a finite set

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I'm solving exercise $1.1.2$ of Hodges' *Model Theory*:

> Let $X$ be a set and $L$ a signature; write $\kappa (X,L)$ for the number of distinct $L$-structures which have domain $X$. Show that if $X$ is a finite set, then $\kappa (X,L)$ is eithere finite or at least $2^\omega$.

This is what I came up with:

> Let $L$ be a signature. There are three possibilities:
>
> 1. **$L$ has a finite number of relations and operations**. Thus is quite trivial to understand why there are at most a finite number of $L$-structures on $X$. We observe $n$-ary relations (and also $(n-1)$-ary functions) are subsets of $X^n$, which is finite by hypothesis, and you have at most $2^{2^n}$ possible interpretations for each $n$-ary symbol of $L$. Having $L$ a finite number of relations and operations, $\kappa(X,L)$ is a finite multiplications of finite cardinals, thus finite.
> 2. **$L$ has a countably infinite number of relations or operations**. Then by the same line of reasoning, you get
>      $$
>     \kappa(X,L) \geq \prod_{k_n : n\in\Bbb{N}} 2^{2^{k_n}} = 2^{\sum_{k_n:n\in\Bbb{N}} 2^{k_n}} = 2^\omega.
>    $$
>      Where we enumerated the relations and operations symbols of $L$ and defined $k_n$ to be the arity of the $n$-th symbol (if the symbol is an operation, add $1$ to the arity).
> 3. **$L$ has an uncountably infinite number of relations or operations**. Then, if you select a countable subset of the symbols, the reduced signature has at least $2^\omega$ structures implementing it. Thus $\kappa(X,L) \geq 2^\omega$ for sure.

I'm very doubtful my reasoning is rigorous, especially from a set-theoretic standpoint. I'll appreciate corrections.

Thank you.

Comment: If $X$ has only one element and $L$ is infinite but has only operation symbols (no relations), then the number of structures is smaller than you said.

Comment: @AndreasBlass you're right. Don't you get $\kappa(X, L) =\omega$ in that case?

Comment: No, in that case you get $\kappa(X,L)=1$, because the interpretation of each operation symbol is completely determined: it has to map to the one and only element of $X$.

Comment: Right. I got confused thinking about the possible *signatures*...